# target_schema ignored by dbt on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, dbt

I have been trying to add a target_schema in the `dbt_project.yml` as well as in the model file itself.

```
models:
  project_name:
    model_name:
      +target_schema: new_schema
```

To my understanding and what I read here in the [official documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/custom-schemas), this should work. But it is ignored instead and shows up as the standard `dbo`. I created the schema by hand to make sure it exists and if I set a `schema` it creates one, in the format `dbo_schema` just as described in the documentation. But the `target_schema` keeps getting ignored?

Is this simply not supported by SQL Server and dbt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no config called `target_schema`. The [docs you link to](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/custom-schemas#advanced-custom-schema-configuration) use that name for the schema config defined in your active target, which is configured in your [`profiles.yml`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/profiles.yml) file:

```yaml
# profiles.yml
my_profile:
  target: dev # this is the default target
  outputs:
    dev:
      schema: dbo # this is what the docs call target_schema
```

On an individual model (or a directory of models), you can additionally set a config that is also just called `schema`. This sets what the docs call a `custom_schema`. This config is read from `dbt_project.yml`, a "properties" `.yml` file, or from a `{{ config() }}` block in a model file.

```yaml
# dbt_project.yml
models:
  project_name:
    model_name:
      +schema: new_schema # this sets what the docs call custom_schema
```

The above two config files together will materialize `model_name` to a schema called `dbo_new_schema`, as explained in the docs that you link to, since the default behavior is `<target_schema>_<custom_schema>`.

If you just want to materialize *all* of your models to `new_schema`, then change the value in your `profiles.yml` file, and do not set a `schema` config in your `dbt_project.yml` or anywhere else. If you only want **some** models materialized to `new_schema`, then I recommend sticking with the default convention for custom schemas, since that'll generalize better to multiple environments (for developers, QA, etc.). Finally, if that really isn't what you want, [the docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/custom-schemas#advanced-custom-schema-configuration) describe how to override the custom schema name-generating behavior.